# Variable not correlating with other variables - reason for deletion in PCA?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

When I run PCA on a set of variables, I notice that there is one variable that has very low correlations with the other variables and also most of the correlations are not statistically significant. Should this variable be the first to be deleted and then run PCA with the other variables or would this be a mistake to do?

Comment: PCA is an exploratory tool, like, say, a magnifying glass. You can apply it to any number of variables you want, "deleting" any of them, adding others, whatever. Nothing of that is ever "a mistake", in the same sense as looking through a magnifying glass is never "a mistake", whatever you decide to look at. You are presumably asking your question having a very specific goal of the PCA analysis in mind. Please start with this goal and explain it in detail, otherwise your questions will remain unanswerable. It's not a coincidence that most of your questions have 0 answers and 0 upvotes.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have tried solutions with both keeping that variable in PCA as well as deleting it from the start. It seems that in the case when I do not delete it from the start it leads to solutions that are less plausible. So I am guessing that it is because that variable does does significantly correlate with most of the other variables. I have been searching the literature but the criterias for inclusion.deleting the variables in PCA do not seem to include this aspect (I have found only one reference but it is not clear).

Comment: Also, this variable has a MSA that is much lower the the other variables, but would meet the minimal values of 0,50. So I am not sure what to do with it, to obtain the most appropriate solution, considering PCA rules.

Comment: The whole point of my previous comment was that there are no "PCA rules", but apparently I failed to communicate it.

Comment: I understood what you were saying from the beginning. But though the process I guided after some general rules that apply for factor analysis. The statistical programme that I am using has the option of factor analysis, with principal component method for extraction of components, so I'm guessing its the same as referring to PCA. This is the reason I have reffered to some guidelines for deletion of variables.

Comment: Lucy: `I have tried solutions with both keeping as well as deleting... in the case when I do not delete ... it leads to solutions that are less plausible.` This is a bad kind of experimenting in a real life study. A decision to choose should, most cases, not depend on "plausible" results. Rather, you should be aware what consequences your decision may bring. Which implies that you must know the theory behind the analysis, to a sufficient extent.

Comment: I was refering to the theory when I mentioned about plausible results. I would like to base my decision on which alternative is better regarding variables that do not correlate significantly with other variables (to be deleted or kept in the analysis - in PCA) but could not find debates about this issue.

Comment: Lucy, your question should start with something like that: I have such and such data, and I am using PCA as a method of Factor Analysis to obtain such and such goals. Without such clarification, all your questions about "what is better?" are **meaningless**, because there is no better or worse here! There are only rules of thumb that apply to specific applications.

Comment: Lucy, in reply to your last comment: 1) Adding or deletion a variable may, irrespective of how strongly it correlates with the rest, change results of PCA strongly. 2) In FA (even when done by means of PCA) we usually want to "explain" correlations (rather than variance). In this respect, what is the worth to explain zero correlations? It is resonable therefore to omit a variable if it doesn't correlate with the rest, because that variable is entirely the unique factor on its own.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Amoeba, I will be more specific in the future. Ttnphns - "It is resonable therefore to omit a variable if it doesn't correlate with the rest, because that variable is entirely the unique factor on its own." - this was my guess as well but I was not sure. Some authore use a specific set of guidelines for deleting variables, under the premise that all variables can be initially included and they do not mention about variables that do not correlate with other, and thus would be unique factors on their own.